# How does it snow on Google, by typing Let it snow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know Google is actually promoting CSS3 and HTML5. I have seen that "

> do a barrell roll

" will rotate the page. but I am not sure how it snows when you type

> Let it snow

is this a  CSS3 trick or a javascript?

**EDIT UPDATE:**

I tried this trick by disabling javascript and it did work STILL, so it is not a javascript

Comment: They are animating `*` within `DIV`s in a main `DIV` overlaid the screen, using `position: absolute` and `left` and `top` offsets. Right-click and inspect it (using Firebug or Chrome Console) after it starts to see what I mean.

Comment: Hadn't seen the "let it snow" one yet.  Cool!

Comment: This question IS inspired by DamnLOL!! Isn't it? I saw it today as well. =) http://www.damnlol.com/let-it-snow-12049.html

Comment: It is first time using canvas tag to show the frost and the snowflakes. At this time, the search results can't be clicked because canvas element is on top of them. When you click 'Defrost', canvas is removed and the effect of falling snowflakes is shown by using animation divs which has ❄ as mentioned by Jared Farrish

Answer (score 4):

By inspect its code with Chrome's Developer Tool, I think it's done with HTML5 Canvas Element.
And here is my clone of the frost effect: http://wong2.github.com/SnowClone
get my code at: https://github.com/wong2/SnowClone

Comment: Nice effect, Google is  also changing the search bar to defrost after there has been considerable snow on the page :P)